# Connecting to api through php (traileraddict)

Tags: php

I'm connecting to traileraddict.com. I can make the connection and display the 8 newest trailers in localhost. But when I load the page to the internet it won't display.

here is the exsample from trailer addict

```
<?php 

$upcoming = simplexml_load_file("http://api.traileraddict.com/?featured=yes&count=8"); 

foreach($upcoming->trailer as $x => $updates) 
{ 
   echo $updates->title; 
   echo '<br>'; 
   echo '<span style="font-size:x-small">Source: <a href="'. $updates->link .'">TrailerAddict</a></span>'; 
   echo '<br>'; 
   //now echo the embedded trailer 
   echo $updates->embed; 
   echo '<br><br>';     

    } 
    ?>
```

And here is the error message I receive when I load it into the server.

```
Warning: simplexml_load_file(): http:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_fopen=0 in /heima/sth132/.public_html/Lokaverkefnireal/php/trailers.php on line 3 Warning: simplexml_load_file(http://api.traileraddict.com/?featured=yes&count=8): failed to open stream: no suitable wrapper could be found in /heima/sth132/.public_html/Lokaverkefnireal/php/trailers.php on line 3 Warning: simplexml_load_file(): I/O warning : failed to load external entity "http://api.traileraddict.com/?featured=yes&count=8" in /heima/sth132/.public_html/Lokaverkefnireal/php/trailers.php on line 3 Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /heima/sth132/.public_html/Lokaverkefnireal/php/trailers.php on line 5 Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /heima/sth132/.public_html/Lokaverkefnireal/php/trailers.php on line 5
```

Bare in mind that don't have access to the server witch host's the site and I have also checked out related subject on stack, witch I don't under stand at all. So if you could help me that would be fantastic

Comment: You can't solve this without access to the server. Contact your host about this problem.

Comment: Your host is the problem. They do not allow your method. Check with them

Answer (score 1):

That is because the server's configuration prevents it from directly opening URLs from `simplexml_load_file()`, so you should first download the page using Curl :

```
// create curl resource
$ch = curl_init();

// set url
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://api.traileraddict.com/?featured=yes&count=8");

//return the transfer as a string
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

// $output contains the output string
$output = curl_exec($ch);

// close curl resource to free up system resources
curl_close($ch);

// load the previously downloaded XML page
$upcoming = simplexml_load_string($output);

// continue as usual (foreach $upcoming...)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help and input but I did as you asked. Like but then I get this error

[blocked] The page at 'https://notendur.hi.is/~sth132/Lokaverkefnireal/index_Lokaverkefni.php#' was loaded over HTTPS, but ran insecure content from 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js': this content should also be loaded over HTTPS.
 index_Lokaverkefni.php:1

And then I added https and got this as you can see on my site under trailers in navbar           https://notendur.hi.is/~sth132/Lokaverkefnireal/index_Lokaverkefni.php#

Comment: Thanks for you help but this did almost work. If you look at my page under trailers in navbar you can see it don't post the videos.  https://notendur.hi.is/~sth132/Lokaverkefnireal/index_Lokaverkefni.php#

Comment: @jonjonson That's because you link to the embedded movie trailer which is served over HTTP while serving your page over HTTPS, that causes a [mixed content](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Security/MixedContent) error; see if there's a way to get the trailer over HTTPS.

Comment: This is the error I get..........................................[blocked] The page at 'https://notendur.hi.is/~sth132/Lokaverkefnireal/index_Lokaverkefni.php#' was loaded over HTTPS, but ran insecure content from 'http://www.traileraddict.com/emd/83428': this content should also be loaded over HTTPS.

Comment: @jonjonson That's exactly what I said before, either find a way to get the trailers over HTTPS or serve the main page over HTTP.

Comment: Sorry didn't see the former answer but thank you again and I'll find that out